# how to move to the top an array element

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have selected rows from a table
target row is a row having `id` equal to `$_GET['id']`
I want to move it at the top of rows

```
$sq = "select * from video order by ind asc";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute();
$rows = $st->fetchAll();

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if($row['id'] == $_GET['id']){
            unset($rows[$row]);  // error line
            $rows = $row + $rows;
        }
    }
}
```

error - `Illegal offset type in unset...`
also - is there a shorter way to do this, i.e. to avoid loop
something like:

```
$rows[having id equal to $_GET['id']] -> move-to-top
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line,

```
unset($rows[$row]);  // error line
```

you need to unset the key in `$rows` and not `$row` itself which is a value in the foreach loop.

So, for unsetting it would look like:

```
<?php

foreach($rows as $key => $row){
    if($row['id'] == $_GET['id']){
        unset($rows[$key]); 
        // code line to move to the top 
        break;
    }
}
```

Don't use `$rows = $row + $rows;` kind of syntax as it makes it difficult to read during code reviews.

For a shorter syntax, you can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out the row and then perform a swap taking the help of [`symmetric-array-destructuring`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$row = array_filter($rows, fn($arr) => $arr['id'] == $testID);
[$rows[array_keys($row)[0]], $rows[0]] = [$rows[0], $rows[array_keys($row)[0]]];
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/76df7)

Comment: thanks a lot. Can't believe - there is no a function - to move elements up and down in php

Comment: @provance Glad to help. To be honest, it isn't really a very common use case for PHP devs to create inbuilt functions for such swaps. However, to push things to the end, you do have `array_push`, but to move to the top, it would involve reindexing the entire array.